# What's the best way to download multiple images and display multiple UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image

I need to download images from a website and display them on(?) multiple UIImageView.

Maybe I'll code a php to "read" the directory and search for images, write a XML file and use it as medium. But I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Comment: Check out SQLite. This is the database used by iOS devices and CoreData. NSPredicates are the objects that you can use for SQL-like queries. I attempted to do the same thing last year, but at the time it was a little out of my abilities, but this should help you start out. I also believe that your suppose to use JSON. Lynda.com has a course for this if you are a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the options you have to fetch images from a website:

1. Fetching HTML and Parsing the HTML to find the images (on the iphone). Then downloading the images.
2. Writing a script (maybe PHP) that writes all image links to an XML file (or JSON), and then fetch the output of your script with all the links.

If you choose option (1) you'll need [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to fetch data asynchronously (without blocking the UI). I would also use [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) to parse HTML using xpath queries, see [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) tutorial for help. Finally to fetch the images using their URLs you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), SDWebimage also provides caching so your app will not download the same image multiple times.

The bad side of using option (1) is that any change in the Website you're getting the images from will break your app and you'll need to issue an update to the app store in order to fix it.

If you choose option (2), your app will be easier to fix if the website changes, you'll just need to modify your script.

If you go with option (2) you'll probably need [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (or a third party XML parsing library) and to download the images I would recomend [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) again. I would also advise using JSON (and [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) instead of XML, just beacuse I find JSON easier to parse.

Comment: Thank's for your time and awesome reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be very good if you write some php script to get image list (list of image urls).
After getting such urls you can asynchronously download and show them in image views. Look [here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/) for such async image view implementation